# What's the translation of the adjective "smexy" in French?

Tags: traduction, adjectifs

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/smexy:

> smexy (comparative smexier, superlative smexiest): (colloquial, slang) Embodying the qualities of sex appeal and intelligence

What's the translation of the adjective "smexy" in French? Google Translate and Linguee weren't helpful.

Comment: Il n'est pas étonnant qu'un traducteur en ligne qui a pour base de données  les textes du parlement européen, des brevets et de l’Unesco ne connaisse pas un mot d'argot qui n'est même pas encore référencé dans les dictionnaires papier. On ne peut s'amuser qu'à faire un néologisme (sextil sextel, sapiosexy, etc...) mais il se pourrait bien que d'ici quelques années ce soit le mot anglais qui passe en français !

Comment: Ben... apparemment je retarde sur le quelques années... Lee Salvino est présentée comme un [« auteur de romances smexy (smart+sexy) »](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Serment_de_l_Alpha/ExXgEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22le+serment+de+l%27alpha%22+smexy&pg=PT275&printsec=frontcover).  Et aussi trouvé smexy sur un forum québécois. J'ajouterais bien « brixy » à la liste ci-dessus mais je doute que ça passe... déjà que smart commence aussi a être utilisé en français pour dire intelligent et pas seulement élégant !

Comment: Mais non! Ca se traduit par "Frank" ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there's a translation to begin with. It's obviously a pun that exists only because the two words are easy to mash together. How you say it in French is however you'd say it in English if you were to paraphrase it. Probably just a literal translation of "smart and sexy".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat  A pun that exists only because the two words are easy to mash together can sometimes have a translation.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat E.g., mansplain = mecspliquer (or pénispliquer, in Canadian French).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There isn't (yet?) an equivalent word in French.

It seems like someone people borrowed the expression directly from English, but those cases are rare enough that one couldn't say this is officially a French word (like "sexy" is).

Perhaps this word's use will spread enough to enter French discourses, or perhaps another will instead. Anyway it is too early to know.